# Is it possible to use DocBlocks with dreamweaver cs5?

Tags: dreamweaver, docblocks

I like documenting php with netbeans, but it doesn't seem to work with dreamweaver cs5.

Comment: I'm confused as to what your you're asking for. There's nothing stopping you from writing DocBlocks in your PHP code. What specifically do you mean by "use DocBlocks" with Dreamweaver?

Comment: like using it as an IDE like netbeans, where you enter a function and it will pop a helper to point what kind of argument you can put in it (i'm super noob) but base on your question I guess it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are writing a function in PHP, Dreamweaver does not automatically add any comments such as DocBlocks to the code. You can add them yourself quite easily, I'd suggest adding a Snippet with the basics of a DocBlock.

Dreamweaver can pop up code hints for PHP functions; it gleans what should be presented to the user from the actual PHP code itself, that is from the function signature, not from any comments associated with the function. See this [video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-dreamweaver-cs5/using-php-code-hinting-in-dreamweaver-cs5/) that show a bit of PHP hints. So it seems that for what it appears that your trying to ask: no, you do not get code hints from DocBlock in Dreamweaver, but you do get PHP code hints.

Comment: the video provided the informations concisely for what I need, as it seems dreamweaver can work as an IDE but for documentation it still lack DocBlocks capabilities. tx